# Do cockroaches eat their shells after moulting?

Tags: zoology, entomology

I recently witnessed a cockroach eat its shell after it moulted. Do cockroaches always do this?

Comment: I have read that spiders eat their webs to re-spin them somewhere else. Eating a shell Might be some form of recycling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's fairly common for insects to eat their egg casings, shed skin etc. where possible. In a similar vein, as Alex Stone mentions, [spiders often eat their webs](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jez.1401760302/abstract) too. There's generally plenty of valuable protein and nutrients tied up in there, so why not recycle?

Comment: Thank you for the link! I thought along the line of recycling but I wasn't sure.